# Outlook 365 "mail from" search folder can't display Deleted Items

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Trying to create a search folder that displays all the messages from specific users, even deleted ones. But a simple search folder for "Mail from specific people" does not show me any items in Deleted Items. Is that a known issue? It does let me select that folder when I customize the search for which folders to look in.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook, go to File > Options > Search > Results and make sure that **Include messages from the Deleted items folder in each data file when searching in All Items** is enabled:

[image]

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided?